# Goto and Code Repetition - Are they avoidable in this case?

Tags: c, loops, goto

I've recently faced a programming problem, and it seems to me that the most optimized way of solving it is by using goto, even though it's not a good practice. The problem is: tell the user to enter a positive natural number ( > 0) and read the input. If this number is valid, tell the user the square of that number. Do this while the input is correct. I came up with a few solutions, but all of them seem to have problems. Here are two of them:
Solution 1 - Problem: Uses goto

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;

_LOOP:
    printf("Enter a positive natural number: ");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    if (num > 0) {
        printf("Square: %i\n", num * num);
        goto _LOOP;
    }

    printf("Invalid number\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Solution 2 - Problem: Double-checks if num > 0 (code repetition)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;

    do {
        printf("Enter a positive natural number: ");
        scanf("%i", &num);

        if (num > 0)
            printf("Square: %i\n", num * num);
    } while (num > 0);
    
    printf("Invalid number\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, there are more ways to solve the problem, but all the other ones I came up with that do not use goto encouter the same code repetition problem. So, is there a solution where both goto and code repetitions are avoided? If not, which one should I go for?

Comment: You might be interested in the `continue` and `break` statements.

Comment: I'm reluctant to post an actual answer but ... an 'infinite' `while(1) { ... }` loop with an `if (num <= 0) break;` just after the `scanf` call would do the trick. It's a fairly common 'paradigm' in C and C++.

Comment: Still, there is a conditional loop - while(true) - that checks another condition inside it - if (num <= 0). The goto solution only does a single check. I wonder if that has an impact in performance...

Comment: @rdbo There is no condition. The compiler will replace it with unconditional branch instruction.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh, I see what you're saying. Because the loop always branches, the compiler will make sure that the program will not even check the condition, therefore achieving the same result as the goto and avoiding it at the same time

Comment: @rdbo That's right

Comment: If you want to do "safe" input, checking the user's input for validity and re-prompting for another try if invalid, that's totally worth encapsulating in a separate function, like `get_int()` or something.  Encapsulating it as a function has multiple benefits, not least of which is clarifying things if you've got an outer loop prompting the user for multiple inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's half the answer; try to fill in what's missing. Remember that sometimes it's better to structure your loop as "do something until..." rather than "do something while..."

```
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter a positive natural number: ");
        scanf("%i", &num);
        if (num <= 0)
            break;
        printf("Square: %i\n", num * num);
    }
    printf("Invalid number\n");
```

[updated with @rdbo's answer]

Comment: Add `if (num <= 0) break;` so I can mark this as the solution (edit queue is full). I got to know that because the loop always branches, it has the same impact in the execution flow as the goto used in my solution, and still avoids it.

Answer (score 0):

What about breaking out of the loop? This is basically a `goto` statement to the end of the loop without explicitly using `goto`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;

    while(1) {
        printf("Enter a positive natural number: ");
        scanf("%i", &num);

        if (num > 0) {
            printf("Square: %i\n", num * num);
        } else {
            printf("Invalid number\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, `break;` is like a `goto` to *the statement **immediately following** the enclosing loop*.  The `continue` statement is more like a "goto the *end* of the loop."

Answer (score 0):

For starters if you expect a non-negative number then the variable `num` should have an unsigned integer type for example `unsigned int`.

As it is written in your question the user can enter an invalid data or interrupt the input. You have to process such a situation.

Also the multiplication `num * num` can result in an overflow.

And using `goto` instead of a loop is indeed a bad idea.

Pay attention to that you should declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

To use the for loop for such a task is also a bad idea. It is much expressive to use a while loop.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        printf( "Enter a positive natural number: " );
        
        unsigned int num;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &num ) != 1 || num == 0 ) break;

        printf( "Square: %llu\n", ( unsigned long long )num * num );
    }

    puts( "Invalid number" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a positive natural number: 100000000
Square: 10000000000000000
Enter a positive natural number: 0
Invalid number
```

Or it would be even better to move the last output statement inside the while statement. Fo rexample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        printf( "Enter a positive natural number: " );
        
        unsigned int num;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &num ) != 1 || num == 0 )
        {
            puts( "Invalid number" );
            break;
        }
        
        printf( "Square: %llu\n", ( unsigned long long )num * num );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option: check a bool that stores if the continue condition is met. It reads much easier than the infinite loop/break approaches (to me) and there's no code repetition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    bool bContinue;

    do {
        printf("Enter a positive natural number: ");
        scanf("%i", &num);

        if (num > 0){
            printf("Square: %i\n", num * num);
            bContinue = true;
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid number\n");
            bContinue = false;
        }
    } while (bContinue);             

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit surprised nobody suggested functional decomposition yet.
Instead of writing a big pile of primitive statements, cut `main` up into smaller functions.
Apart from readability/maintainability benefits, it also helps eliminate code duplication in a very natural way.

In OP's case, getting input from the end user is a separate responsibility, and makes a good choice for a separate function.

```c
static bool user_enters_number(int *ptr_to_num)
{
    printf("Enter a positive natural number: ");
    return scanf("%i", ptr_to_num) == 1;
}
```

Notice `user_enters_number` explicitly tests the return value of `scanf`.
This improve end-of-file handling.

Likewise, you could give number validation its own function.
This may seem like overkill (it's just `num > 0`, right?), but it gives us the opportunity to combine the validation with the resulting error message.
Printing "Invalid number" at the end of `main` feels wrong. Invalid numbers are not the only exit condition; end-of-file is another.
So instead, I will let the validation function determine the message.
As a bonus, this makes it possible to support multiple error types (e.g. separate messages for negative numbers and for zero).

```c
static bool is_valid_number(int num)
{
    bool ok = (num > 0);
    if (!ok) printf("Invalid number\n");
    return ok;
}
```

We now have two boolean-typed functions that can be neatly chained together with `&&` and put inside the condition part of a loop, which is an idiomatic way of saying: if either one of these functions fails (i.e. returns false), immediately exit the loop.

What's left, is a very clean `main` function.

```c
int main(void)
{
    int num;
    while (user_enters_number(&num) && is_valid_number(num))
    {
        printf("Square: %i\n", num * num);
    }
}
```

To appreciate the benefits in terms of maintainability, try rewriting this code so that it accepts two numbers and prints their product.

```c
int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2;
    while (user_enters_number(&num1) && is_valid_number(num1) &&
           user_enters_number(&num2) && is_valid_number(num2))
    {
        printf("Product: %i\n", num1 * num2);
    }
}
```

The changes are trivial, and limited to a single function
(though you might consider adding a parameter `input_prompt` to `user_enters_number`).

There is no performance penalty for this 'divide-and-conquer' approach: a smart compiler will do whatever is necessary to optimize the code, e.g. inline the functions.